# Outcome error handler, inspired by boost's outcome namespace

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm creating a little library for my pet project that is inspired by Boost's outcome namespace. The main reason why I didn't want to use the Boost version is that I don't like the overhead of including something so massive just for something small like this.

## Source code:

```cpp
using u64 = uint64_t;
using i32 = int32_t;

/**
 * \brief Base error class
 */
class error {
    static inline std::unordered_map<u64, std::string> m_error_templates = {
        { 100, "error occurred while creating 'Hello', today's date is: {:%Y-%m-%d}"},
        { 200, "something messed up in the 'world!' creation process, system has {} threads"}
    };

    error() = delete;
    error(
        u64 error_code, 
        std::string message
    ) : m_code(error_code),
    m_message(std::move(message)) {}
public:
    /**
     * \brief Emits a new error using the given \a error code.
     * \tparam error_code Error code of the error to emit
     * \tparam argument_types Argument list types
     * \param arguments Argument list that will be passed to the error template
     * \return \a Error with the given error code and generated error message.
     */
    template<u64 error_code, typename... argument_types>
    static error emit(
        argument_types&&... arguments
    ) {
        const auto iterator = m_error_templates.find(error_code);
        if (iterator == m_error_templates.end()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(std::format("invalid error code used ({})", error_code));
        }

        return error(error_code, std::vformat(
            iterator->second,
            std::make_format_args(std::forward<argument_types>(arguments)...)
        ));
    }

    /**
     * \brief Prints the given error.
     */
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "error (" << m_code << "):   " << m_message << '\n';
    }
private:
    u64 m_code;
    std::string m_message;
};

/**
 * \brief Outcome namespace, contains containers for handling and propagating errors.
 */
namespace outcome {
    /**
     * \brief Base \a failure class, can be emitted with an \a error.
     */
    class failure {
    public:
        failure() = delete;

        /**
         * \brief Creates a new failure case containing the given \a error.
         * \param error Error to use as the reason for failure
         */
        failure(
            const error& error
        ) : m_error(error) {}

        /**
         * \brief Returns the contained error.
         */
        const error& get_error() const {
            return m_error;
        }
    private:
        error m_error;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Base success class, used for handling success cases with no success return types.
     */
    class success {};

    /**
     * \brief Base result class, contains information about the outcome of an operation.
     * \tparam type Type of the successful outcome
     */
    template<typename type>
    class result {
    public:
        /**
         * \brief Move constructor.
         */
        constexpr result(
            result&& other
        ) noexcept {
            m_value = other.m_value;
        }

        /**
         * \brief Constructs a result from a failure.
         */
        constexpr result(
            failure&& failure
        ) : m_value(std::unexpected(failure.get_error())) {}

        /**
         * \brief Constructs a result from a success.
         */
        constexpr result(
            success&& success
        ) : m_value() {}

        /**
         * \brief Constructs a result from a given value.
         */
        template<typename current_type>
        constexpr result(
            current_type&& value
        ) : m_value(std::forward<current_type>(value)) {}

        /**
         * \brief Checks if the result contains an error.
         */
        bool has_error() const {
            return !m_value.has_value();
        }


        /**
         * \brief Checks if the result contains a value.
         */
        bool has_value() const {
            return m_value.has_value();
        }

        /**
         * \brief Returns the encapsulated value.
         */
        const type& get_value() const {
            return m_value.value();
        }

        /**
         * \brief Returns the encapsulated error.
         */
        const error& get_error() const {
            return m_value.error();
        }
    private:
        std::expected<type, error> m_value;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Specialization of the \a result class for void type.
     */
    template<>
    class result<void> {
    public:
        constexpr result(
            result&& other
        ) noexcept {
            m_value = other.m_value;
        }

        constexpr result(
            failure&& failure
        ) : m_value(std::unexpected(failure.get_error())) {}

        constexpr result(
            success&& success
        ) : m_value() {}

        bool has_error() const {
            return !m_value.has_value();
        }

        bool has_value() const {
            return m_value.has_value();
        }

        const error& get_error() const {
            return m_value.error();
        }
    private:
        std::expected<void, error> m_value;
    };
}

#define CONCATENATE(x, y) _CONCATENATE(x, y)
#define _CONCATENATE(x, y) x ## y

/**
 * \brief Attempts to call the given \a __function, if the outcome of the
 * function call is erroneous immediately returns from the parent function/method.
 * \param __success Variable declaration used for storing the successful result
 * \param __function Function to execute
 */
#define OUTCOME_TRY(__success, __function)                                    \
    auto CONCATENATE(result, __LINE__) = __function;                          \
    if(CONCATENATE(result, __LINE__).has_error())                             \
        return outcome::failure((CONCATENATE(result, __LINE__)).get_error()); \
    __success = CONCATENATE(result, __LINE__).get_value()
```

## Example usage:

```cpp
outcome::result<std::string> generate_hello(
    bool emit_error
) {
    if(emit_error) {
        return outcome::failure(
            error::emit<100>(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
        );
    }

    return "Hello";
}

outcome::result<std::string> generate_world(
    bool emit_error
) {
    if (emit_error) {
        return outcome::failure(
            error::emit<200>(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
        );
    }

    return " world!";
}

outcome::result<std::string> test() {
    OUTCOME_TRY(const auto& hello, generate_hello(false));
    OUTCOME_TRY(const auto& world, generate_world(false));

    return hello + world;
}

i32 main() {
    // capture propagated errors
    const auto& result = test();
    if(result.has_value()) {
        std::cout << "value: " << result.get_value() << '\n';
    }
    else {
        result.get_error().print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unnecessary code

Your classes are actually just very thin wrappers over `std::expected` and `std::unexpected`. With some minor changes (like replacing `get_value()` with `value()`, `has_error()` with `!has_value()`), you can just do:

```
namespace outcome {
    template<typename T>
    using failure = std::unexpected<T>;

    template<typename T>
    using result = std::expected<T, error>;
}
```

And the rest of your code will compile and do the same thing!

## Unnecessary templating of `error::emit()`

I don't see any point in passing `error_code` as a template parameter to `error::emit()`. Nothing is `constexpr` here. If the compiler can somehow specialize and optimize based on the `error_code`, it can still do that if it's passed as a regular function parameter.

If you really want to make use of the template parameter, then instead of storing the error messages in a `std::unordered_map`, use variable templates and template specialization instead:

```
class error {
    template<u64 error_code>
    static const char* error_template{};
    …
public:
    template<u64 error_code, …>
    static error emit(…) {
        return {error_code, std::vformat(error_template<error_code>, …)};
    }
    …
};

template<> const char* error::error_template<100> = "error occured while creating 'Hello', today's date is: {:%Y-%m-%d}";
template<> const char* error::error_template<200> = "something messed up in the 'world!' creation process, system has {} threads";
```

## Consider using `std::error_code` instead of `class error`

Your `class error` looks very similar to [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code). I would use the latter instead of reinventing the wheel. You can create a custom error category (derived from [`std::error_category`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category)) for your own errors.

## Avoid creating aliases for built-in types

It might save a little bit of typing, but I recommend you don't create `u64` and `i32` aliases. In particular, don't declare those aliases in a header file in the global namespace. Just write `std::uint64_t` and `std::int32_t`. If you have a project that includes multiple libraries, it's easy to get lots of different aliases for the same type (making grepping harder), and adds potential for conflicts.

## `main()` returns `int`, not `i32`

There is only one valid return type for `main()`, and that is `int`. While `i32` might be an alias for `int` on some platforms, there are other platforms where this is not the case, and thus would probably cause a compile error.

## Don't use `const` references to hold returned values

In `main()` you wrote:

```
const auto& result = test();
```

However, `test()` returns an outcome *by value*. The `const auto` reference will cause the temporary return value's lifetime to be extended, so it still works fine, but I would just write:

```
auto result = test();
```

You wouldn't write this either, even though it compiles:

```
const auto& pi = 3.1415;
```